# I get this error when I´m using SessionProvider from next/auth/react: "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL"

Tags: session, next.js, node-modules, next-auth

I´m coding an application in nextjs, and I want to implement NextAuth to the project. And in order to do that according to the docs we need to use SessionProvider. And that´s when i get the error message : "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL"

I have tried to upgrade and downgrade my node version(currently using 16.17.0) but that didn´t help.
If i could understand what URL the error message implies it would be a big step forward.

Answer (score 2):

in you .env file use just need to add  the NEXTAUTH_URL if you are on the localhost just put this

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

if your website is deployed put your website url

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=yourwebsitedomain
```

[image]

Comment: I see totally missed it, thank you